# Coming to catch if a statement in try gives error

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch

I am using `async` `await`, from one function to another with `try` `catch` statements for catching errors. Here `function1` and `function2` are on different files:

```
function1 = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const foo = await function2(req.body.name);
        res.status(200).send(foo);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e);
    }
}


function2 = async (name) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.find({name: name});
        if (result) return result;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

If the error comes in the `db.find` it goes to catch statement of `function2`. How to make sure that if it comes to catch statement of `function2` then the return goes to catch statement of `function1`

Comment: Uh, don't `return` errors? If you don't throw an exception (or otherwise reject the promise), no `catch` statement will run.

Comment: What's the point of the `try`/`catch` in `function2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use throw to send error to upper level functions, in your case you can do

```
function2 = async (name) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.find({name: name});
        if (result) return result;
    } catch (e) {
      // do some logging if needed, like
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

also if you are not doing any logging or error handling in function2 you should not use try catch, it will directly handled by function1

```
function2 = async (name) => {
         const result = await db.find({name: name});
        if (result) return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `throw e` here is snippet

```js
// test wrapper
let db = { find: (x) => new Promise((res,rej)=>setTimeout(x=>rej('NO DATA'),1000)) }

function1 = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Find...');
        const foo = await function2('abc');
        console.log('func1');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('outer err', e);
    }
}

function2 = async (name) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.find({name: name});
        console.log('func2');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('inner err', e);
        throw e;
    }
}

function1(0,0);
```